# What would be the over all speed-up achieved?

Tags: parallel-computing

Suppose we are using a dual core processor and we run 2 applications (1 with 80% resource requirements and the other with 20% resource requirements).
Now the first program is parallelizable for 40% and the second one not parallelizable.
My question is what would be the speed up achieved in this case.
By speed-up i mean the ratio between the execution times before and after parallelization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Look up Amdahl's Law on your favorite search engine and plug your question into the equation you find.